# Getting new full calendar event in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap modal to display event details. When the event will be clicked  the start, end and title will be displayed in the popup.

The events are created using a boostrap modal form.

Here is the code

```
$(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: { 
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
     },
    views: {
      month: {
        titleFormat: 'YYYY, MM, DD'
      }
    },
    validRange: function(nowDate) {
      return {
        start: nowDate,
        end: nowDate.clone().add(1, 'months')
      };
    },
    navLinks: true,
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: function(start, end) {
      startDate = moment(new Date(start)).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
      $('#createBookingModal .modal-header .modal-title span').text(startDate);
      $('#createBookingModal').modal('show');
    },
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback){
      $.ajax({
        url: '/api/bookings',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            start: start.unix(),
            end: end.unix(),
        },
        success: function(response){
          var events = [];
          $(response).each(function(){
            events.push({
                title: $(this).attr('title'),
                start: $(this).attr('start_time'),
                end: $(this).attr('end_time'),
            });
          });
          callback(events);
        }
      });
    },
    eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
      //Todo
      //Get event end date here
      console.log(event);
      startDate = moment(new Date(event.start)).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
      endDate = moment(new Date(event.end)).format("MM-DD-YYYY");

      $('#modalTitle').text(event.title);
      $('#modalBody .start span').text(startDate);
      $('#modalBody .end span').text(endDate);
      $('#fullCalModal').modal('show');
    },

    loading: function(bool) {
        $('#loading').toggle(bool);
    }
  });

  $('#submitButton').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      doSubmit();
  });

  function doSubmit(){
    //validate end date here
    endDate = new Date($('#bookingEndDate').val());
    if (! moment(endDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY', true).isValid() ){
      alert('Invalid Date');
    } else {
      eventData = {
        title: $('#bookingName').val(),
        start: new Date($('#createBookingModal .modal-header .modal-title span').text()),
        end: endDate
      };
      $.ajax({
          url: '/api/bookings/create',
          data: {
            title: eventData.title,
            start_time: eventData.start,
            end_time: eventData.end
          },
          success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            // if ( response == 0 ){
            //   alert('Invalid Date');
            //   return false;
            // } else {
            //   return true;
            // }
          }
        });
        $('#createBookingModal form').get(0).reset();
        $("#createBookingModal").modal('hide');
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
    }
  }
});
```

**HTML code**

```
<div class="card-body full-calendar">
                    <div id='calendar'></div>
                    <!-- Display Create Booking form in modal -->
                    <div id="createBookingModal" class="modal fade">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add an Booking on: <span class="startDate"></span>></h4>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> <span class="sr-only">close</span></button>
                                </div>
                                <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body">
                                    <form>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="bookingName">Booking Title</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Booking Name" id="bookingName">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="bookingEndDate">End Date</label>
                                            <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
                                                <input type="text" id="bookingEndDate" class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
                                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <!--<div class="form-group">
                                            <textarea class="form-control" type="text" rows="4" placeholder="Booking Description" id= "eventDescription"></textarea>
                                        </div>-->
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitButton">Save</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Display Booking in modal -->
                <div id="fullCalModal" class="modal fade">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 id="modalTitle" class="modal-title"></h4>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span> <span class="sr-only">close</span></button>
                            </div>
                            <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body">
                                <p class="start">Start At: <span></span></p>
                                <p class="end">End At: <span></span></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                               <!-- <button class="btn btn-primary"><a id="eventUrl" target="_blank">Event Page</a></button>-->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I am not getting the end date for the newly created event when trying to display it in modal, you can notice `//todo`, that is where I want to get end date.May be it need to delegated, but I have no idea how it should be done?

I have added a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hcpjvt6q/), you can see, the end date is coming "01-01-1970", because `eventClick()` is not getting the end date.

**Update**
*It happens only when you are giving same start and end date.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it with just a small workaround, if anyone has a better solution, feel free to post.

```
eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
      if ( event.end == null ){
        event.end = event.start;
      }
      startDate = moment(new Date(event.start)).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
      endDate = moment(new Date(event.end)).format("MM-DD-YYYY");

      $('#modalTitle').text(event.title);
      $('#modalBody .start span').text(startDate);
      $('#modalBody .end span').text(endDate);
      $('#fullCalModal').modal('show');
    },
```

*@ADyson has a huge contribution on this solution, I was expecting to post this as an answer after our discussion, he did not post, so I am posting it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (about 2 years ago!) Had to use submitHandler: function(){} like below

```
 submitHandler: function (form) {
                var dataRow = CreateDataSetup();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "/BookingTwo/SaveEvent",
                    data: dataRow,
                    success: function () {
                        $("#myform")[0].reset();
                        ClearPopupFormValues();
                        $('#popupEventForm').modal('hide');
                    },
                    statusCode: {
                        201: function (response) {
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                            ClearPopupFormValues();
                            showAlert("Success Event Created.", "success", 4000)
                        },
                        500: function (response) {
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                            ClearPopupFormValues();
                            showAlert("Internal Server Error - Logged with System Admins", "danger", 4000)
                            $('#popupEventForm').modal('hide');
                        },
                        400: function (response) {
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                            ClearPopupFormValues();
                            showAlert("Duration Service Returned 0 - Event NOT Created.", "danger", 4000)
                            $('#popupEventForm').modal('hide');
                        },
                        401: function (response) {
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                            ClearPopupFormValues();
                            showAlert("Warning - You do not have permission to delete this.", "danger", 4000)
                            $('#popupEventForm').modal('hide');
                        },
                        403: function (response) {
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                            ClearPopupFormValues();
                            showAlert("Warning - Can't delete approved events.", "danger", 4000)
                        },
                        409: function (response) {
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                            ClearPopupFormValues();
                            showAlert("There is already an event for the user for this date.", "danger", 4000)
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

Also created a DataSetup funtion -

```
    function CreateDataSetup() {
    console.log("Attempting to Setup POST Values...")
    var intEtad = parseInt($('#ETADType').val());
    var intEtadSub = parseInt($('#ETADSubType').val());

    var normStart = $('#LeaveStart').val();
    var normEnd = $('#LeaveFinish').val();

    var ahStart = $('#ADHOCLeaveStart').val();
    var ahEnd = $('#ADHOCLeaveFinish').val();

    var dataRow = {
        'Id': $('#id').val(),
        'Subject': $('#title').val(),
        'Description': $('#customdescription').val(),  
        'StartTime': normStart,
        'EndTime': normEnd,   
        'AHStartTime': ahStart,
        'AHEndTime': ahEnd,
        'SelectRole': $('#SelectRole').val(),
        'ETADType': intEtad,
        'ETADSubType': intEtadSub,
        'StaffID': $('#StaffID').val(),
        'EventStatus': $('#EventStatus').val(),
        'AllRoles': $('#AllRoles').is(':checked'),
        'AllDay': $('#AllDay').is(':checked'),      
        'AM': $('#AM').is(':checked'),
        'PM': $('#PM').is(':checked'),
        'ADHOC': $('#ADHOC').is(':checked'),

    };

    console.log("Setup Complete");
    return dataRow;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I will check and reply to you.

Comment: Theres quite a bit of code not needed to answer the question there, but i just C&P'd from the solution, sorry about that.

Comment: Hello SimonR, Check the discussion, to know I fixed the issue.